# Create table if they do NOT exist

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

Currently there are schema actions that let you recreate tables on each startup, but dropping them obviously means you lose all rows of that table.
In CQL you can make a query like

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyspace.tablename(....)
```

But I can't find any way of achieving a similar result with spring-data-casssandra, one that would let me start my app for the first time and on without changing anything.

Is there any way to create a table defined in a POJO with @Table ONLY if said table does not already exist?

Answer (score 4):

See [DATACASS-219](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-219).

I just recently added support for `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyspace.tablename (..);`.  This will be available in SD Cassandra 1.5 M1 (Ingals).  I'll consider backing porting this to 1.4 for the `1.4.2.RELEASE`.

The only other way to accomplish this for the time being (if not using the `1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` containing the [DATACASS-219](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-219) fix) is to set your `SchemaAction` to `NONE` and provide your own raw CQL, initialization scripts to the `CassandraSessionFactoryBean` using the [setStartupScripts(:List)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/cassandra/config/CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.html#setStartupScripts-java.util.List-) method.

Comment: Under which repository can I find the version containing this fix? Maven doesn't seem to find it in [link](http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/) and although I can see it here [link](http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-cassandra/) it says it was last modified in 06-Apr-2016. Is that the right version ?

Comment: Just solved it, spring boot changes the artifact name so it was looking for it in another directory. Thanks

Comment: Chaging the version to the snapshot raises this error : Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/Timer

Comment: You probably need to include the Netty dependency as the DataStrax Cassandra driver depends on it when doing async ops.  <dependency>
<groupId>io.netty</groupId><artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>    <version>4.0.36.Final</version></dependency>